# Excel drop down list hiding empty fields

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but here goes.
I created a drop-down list in Excel using the Define Name and Data Validation method. In the Define Name phase, I made the area larger so that in the future I can add more items if needed. Once Data Validation is done, the drop down list has the items I created and plenty of empty spaces, which makes sense.

My question is how do I hide these empty fields? Can it be done WITHOUT macros?

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking seems to be simple, when creating the data validator, select list, enable the ignore blank checkbox, select your source (can be a whole column) and select OK, this works for mi on Excel 2016.

[image: Ignore blanks list excel]

If your list contains blanks between them, then you need to sort them or create an auxiliary list in order for the dropdown to only show the non-blank values.